# Setting an Image Buttons's image Xcode Applescript

Tags: objective-c, xcode, applescript

This is what I am trying to do: `on changeSomeImage_(newImage, targetObjectOutlet)

```
set localTarget to current application's NSImage's imageNamed_(newImage)
targetObjectOutlet's setImage_(localTarget)
targetLableOutlet's setStringValue_(newLableText)

end changeSomeImage_
```

I have an IBOutlet connected already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out

```
on changeSomeImage_(newImage, targetObjectOutlet, newText, targetLableOutlet)


set newImage1 to current application's NSImage's imageNamed_(newImage)
targetObjectOutlet's setImage_(newImage1)
targetLableOutlet's setStringValue_(newText)


end changeSomeImage_
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method...

```
changeSomeImage_(newImage, targetObjectOutlet)
```

...is declared wrong. You should name it either

```
-- notice the two underscores for two parameters
change_image_forOutlet(newImage, targetObjectOutlet)
```

Or

```
ChangeImage:newImage forOutlet:targetObjectOutlet
```

Rest of your code looks fine assuming newImage is an NSString with an image title of your resources folder.

Comment: This doesn't work with my code. I am using applescript and no matter where I put this, it fails.